# DateComponents in Swift returns weird values. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm calculating time difference between two dates. I have a piece of code:

```
func timeAgoSinceDate(_ date:Date, numericDates:Bool) -> String {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let now = Date()
    let components:DateComponents = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([NSCalendar.Unit.minute , NSCalendar.Unit.hour , NSCalendar.Unit.day , NSCalendar.Unit.weekOfYear , NSCalendar.Unit.month , NSCalendar.Unit.year , NSCalendar.Unit.second], from: now, to: date, options: NSCalendar.Options())
    print(now)
    print(date)
    print(components.month)
```

and those are some examples that I'm seeing in the console:

```
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000
2017-03-29 16:03:13 +0000
Optional(4) //I think it should return 5?


2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000
2017-01-29 17:03:13 +0000
Optional(2) //again, why 2 instead of 3?

2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000
2015-09-30 15:54:20 +0000
Optional(0) //why 0 since it's almost whole year?


2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000
2016-05-29 14:09:31 +0000
Optional(-5) //this seems to be fine
```

and so on... what's the problem here?

The problem I have is with date calculations. In my code I'm doing:

```
if (components.month! >= 2) {
        return "in \(components.month!) months"
    } else if (components.month! >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "in 1 month"
        } else {
            return "in one month"
        }
    }

    else if (components.month! <= -2) {
        return "\(components.month!) months ago"
    } else if (components.month! <= -1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 month ago"
        } else {
            return "one month ago"
        }
    }
```

and then, because of doing my calculations, currently when one date is `2016-10-29 16:32:54 +0000` and the other one is `2017-01-29 17:03:13 +0000`, the user sees `in 2 months`. That is because the whole `print(components)` returns:

```
year: 0 month: 2 day: 2 hour: 23 minute: 30 second: 18 weekOfYear: 4 isLeapMonth: false
```

but in real life it should return 3 since it's the difference between october and january. Is there any better way of calculating that difference than a bunch of `if` statements that rounds everything down?

Comment: What timezone are you in? The dates are printed in UTC/GMT, but the calendar calculations are done in your *local calendar/timezone.*

Comment: In your first example, it is *less than* 5 month between the given dates, so result 4 is correct.

Comment: hm but I thought that timezone should not affect the calculations in case of `months`... anyway, I'm in `GMT +1`, is there any way of doing the calculations independently of the timezone?

Comment: You can set the calendars time zone to GMT, but even then you would get 4 and not 5 in the first example, and 0 in the third example because the difference is *less* than a year. Try `print(components)` to see the actual difference.

Comment: *Almost* in terms of programming is **not** ;-)

Comment: Guys, I edited my question and added more data - could you take a look and - if there's anything that would work better in my case - let me know how I could change it?

Answer (score 3):

```
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000
2017-03-29 16:03:13 +0000
Optional(4) //I think it should return 5?
```

Since 16:03 is < 16:12, you need to add 9 more minutes and 21 seconds before it would return 5

```
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000
2017-01-29 17:03:13 +0000
Optional(2) //again, why 2 instead of 3?
```

Daylight savings time is Nov 6th, 2016.  You lose an hour.  I'm fairly sure this is why it thinks it's only 2 months of time.

Add an hour:

```
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000
2017-01-29 18:03:13 +0000
Optional(3)
```

You get '3'

Change the months but keep the original hours:

```
2016-7-29 16:12:34 +0000
2016-10-29 17:03:13 +0000
Optional(3)
```

You also get '3'

```
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000
2015-09-30 15:54:20 +0000
Optional(0) //why 0 since it's almost whole year?
```

Date components return the difference of the highest unit you've included in your components definition.  In your case, you've included `NSCalendar.Unit.year`.  Therefore `components.month` will return the month unit, not the total difference in months.  So the month unit in this calculation is the 0 month.  If you were to add 25 years and 5 months to a date, it would return '5'.  However if you were to remove `NSCalendar.Unit.year` then it will use months as the highest unit and return '305'

You can test some dates like this:

```
let startString = "2016-7-30 16:12:34 +0000"
let endString = "2016-10-30 17:03:13 +0000"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let now = formatter.date(from: startString)!
let date = formatter.date(from: endString)!
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 month, 28 days, 23 hours, 50 minutes and 39 seconds from 2016-10-29 16:12:34 to 2017-03-29 16:03:13 and that
is why `components.month` evaluates to `4` in your first example.

If your intention is to compute the difference (in month) from October 2016
to March 2017 then you have to compute the difference between the
*start of the month* of both dates:

```
let startOfFirstMonth = calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: firstDate))!
let startOfSecondMonth = calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: secondDate))!

let comps = calendar.dateComponents([.month], from: startOfFirstMonth, to: startOfSecondMonth)
print(comps.month)
```

Comment: I disagree with the first statement because if you evaluate " from 2016-10-29 to 2017-03-29" without using HH:mm:ss then it does actually evaluate to 5 months.  But the OP's example includes exact times which make it just shy of 5 months. (not my down vote btw)

Comment: @Frankie: You are right, that was abbreviated too much, I have fixed that now, thanks for the feedback! – The proposed solution however should work in all cases of the  question (as I understand it from the update).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is intended to be an additional information for Frankie's answer.

```
func calendarTest(_ from: String, _ to: String) {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Paris")! //<- GMT+1
    let inFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    inFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
    guard
        let now = inFormatter.date(from: from),
        let date = inFormatter.date(from: to)
    else {return}
    //Removing "weeks" for clarity
    let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.minute, .hour, .day/*, .weekOfYear*/, .month, .year, .second], from: now, to: date, options: [])
    let outFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    outFormatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
    print("UTC time                  Localtime")
    print(now, outFormatter.string(from: now))
    print(date, outFormatter.string(from: date))
    print(components)
}
```

With the code above:

```
calendarTest("2016-10-29 16:12:34","2017-03-29 16:03:13")
calendarTest("2016-10-29 16:12:34","2017-03-29 16:12:34")
```

output:

```
UTC time                  Localtime
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000 2016-10-29 18:12:34
2017-03-29 16:03:13 +0000 2017-03-29 18:03:13
year: 0 month: 4 day: 28 hour: 23 minute: 50 second: 39 isLeapMonth: false 
UTC time                  Localtime
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000 2016-10-29 18:12:34
2017-03-29 16:12:34 +0000 2017-03-29 18:12:34
year: 0 month: 5 day: 0 hour: 0 minute: 0 second: 0 isLeapMonth: false
```

---

```
calendarTest("2016-10-29 16:12:34","2017-01-29 17:03:13")
calendarTest("2016-10-29 16:12:34","2017-01-29 17:12:34")
```

output:

```
UTC time                  Localtime
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000 2016-10-29 18:12:34
2017-01-29 17:03:13 +0000 2017-01-29 18:03:13
year: 0 month: 2 day: 30 hour: 23 minute: 50 second: 39 isLeapMonth: false 
UTC time                  Localtime
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000 2016-10-29 18:12:34
2017-01-29 17:12:34 +0000 2017-01-29 18:12:34
year: 0 month: 3 day: 0 hour: 0 minute: 0 second: 0 isLeapMonth: false
```

---

```
calendarTest("2016-10-29 16:12:34","2015-09-30 15:54:20")
```

output:

```
UTC time                  Localtime
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000 2016-10-29 18:12:34
2015-09-30 15:54:20 +0000 2015-09-30 17:54:20
year: -1 month: 0 day: -29 hour: 0 minute: -18 second: -14 isLeapMonth: false
```

---

```
calendarTest("2016-10-29 16:12:34","2016-05-29 14:09:31")
```

output:

```
UTC time                  Localtime
2016-10-29 16:12:34 +0000 2016-10-29 18:12:34
2016-05-29 14:09:31 +0000 2016-05-29 16:09:31
year: 0 month: -5 day: 0 hour: -2 minute: -3 second: -3 isLeapMonth: false
```

Remember `Calendar.current` calculates months with dates & **times** of the local timezone.

---

By the way, you have no need to use `NSCalendar` when getting `DateComponents` between two `Date`s.

```
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.minute, .hour, .day/*, .weekOfYear*/,.month, .year, .second], from: now, to: date)
```